# Get All materials from specific folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to get all materials from a folder into my List. I tried this

```
 AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/Trier Pallien_CROWD/Materials/Female021Skin_001_Color.mat");
```

but it only allow me to get one material. I don't want to put my materail into resource folder so i can't user [Resource.LoadAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html)

Comment: Cant you use a for each *.mat in the directory?

Comment: I've never used that function or any like it but shouldn't you be doing something like: AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/Trier Pallien_CROWD/Materials");

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("Assets/Trier Pallien_CROWD/Materials/");
```